# Implement some method in base class and some method in derived class of one interface

Tags: oop

We have one interface with four normal methods say method1,method2,method3,methid4 and we want to implement only two methods in base class and the other two in derived classes.how we achieve this?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please look at guide [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Just a brief we have an interface with four methods , and we have a base class that inheriting that interfaces means we have to implement all method details in base class then we have an other class derived class inheriting from interface class then by default the derived class also have all base methods , so the main objective here to show only method1 and method 2 in base class and method 3 and method 4 in derived class. With one interface declaration?

Answer (score 1):

You make two interfaces to achieve that. All methods of an interface must be implemented in a class that implements an interface.

Answer (score 1):

[@wdc answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51122614/7362396) is correct, having multiple, smaller interfaces is the solution and probably most compliant with [ISP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle).

Base-Class would implement Interface1, Derived-Class would extend Base-Class and explicitely implement Interface2, so it then has implemented both, as it gets the other one derived. Depending on your language, Interface2 could even extend Interface1.

I just want to add that you **could** also make the Base-Class `abstract`, and would not have to implement all the Interfaces methods. But then you couldn't instanciate it anymore, of course.